# failed: could not find driver

Tags: database, craft3, cli

Craft CMS 3 - I have used the CLI ./craft setup script to set the database connection on my local machine. I setup a MySQL connection, but when it attempts to validate my credentials, I get "failed: could not find driver". However, when I make a direct MySQL CLI connection using the same credentials, it works just fine. Why can Craft CMS not connect to my local database?

Comment: Do you have https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php installed?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone from the future, this worked for me utilizing Ubuntu 16.0.4 with PHP7.2:

Try this command:

```
sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql
```

If it says it cant find the package, install this:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql
```

Check your active php.ini file for this line(*my active .ini was located n /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini*):

```
;extension=pdo_mysql
```

If it has a semicolon before it, remove it, and then save. For good measure, run this again:

```
sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql
```

Restart apache. Good day.